# .htaccess rewrite with characters

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to do some .htaccess to make some beautiful URL's. I am trying to do the following:

```
#profil.php?page=? to profil/?
RewriteRule ^profil/([^a-zA-Z]+)$ /profil.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Actually:

url.dk/profil.php?page=timeline *to* url.dk/profil/timeline

I've been trying to switch around some things like "/" and removing NC,QSA,L and adding R and stuff like that. Nothing seems to work.

It returns in a failure, where Chrome tells me about some looping.

Everything's working before the .htaccess edit. So I don't think it's my script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my self :-)

Result is:

```
RewriteRule ^profil/([^/]+)$ profil.php?page=$1
```